# How to playback containerless / raw .h264 streams via Webcodecs API?

Tags: typescript, webcodecs

I want to play back a raw .h264 stream using the Webcodecs API and extract specific frames. It is saved as a .h264 file, essentially just the video data before being muxed into a .mp4 container format.

It should be possible to play this back using the new [WebCodecs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebCodecs_API). I fail at providing the `avc1.64001e` [VideoDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoDecoder) with the properly formatted [EncodedVideoChunk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EncodedVideoChunk). How can I do so? I know the resolution, framerate and frame count, but how do I take this information and create an EncodedVideoChunk from that?

I have a potentially gigabytes big local file, which I receive via:

```js
        const readableStream = this.data.file.stream();
        const reader = readableStream.getReader();
```

How to feed this into [`VideoDecoder: decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoDecoder/decode)?
I know you can let [`mp4box.js`](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js) handle the demuxing and providing of chunks. But I have the data already demuxed. So how do I overcome this step, besides muxing and feeding it through [`mp4box.js`](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js), only to have it demux again?

Comment: I am also interrested in this, Hope anybody knows that :)

Comment: Hope so too^^  Asked also in the mp4box.js repo: https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/issues/352